# Propel - where and begins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony1, propel

I have table:

```
Article:
ID | TITLE | CONTENT
1  | aaa+s | sdsd
2  | ccc+a | sdsda
3  | aaa+s | dsdsd
4  | aaa+2 | sfsdf
5  | sds+2 | sadasds
```

How to get all Article where title begins of **aaa+** ?

```
           $c = new Criteria();
           $c->add(ArticlePeer::TITLE, ????);
           $art = ArticlePeer::doSelectOne($c);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as a plain MySQL statement:

```
       SELECT * FROM `Article` WHERE TITLE LIKE "aaa+%"
```

In Symfony, it can be done this way:

```
       $c = new Criteria();
       $c->add(ArticlePeer::TITLE, 'aaa+%', Criteria::LIKE);
       $art = ArticlePeer::doSelectOne($c);
```

Check out [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer) table 8 -1  for more details.